# Can I use "doch" as negation to "es ist meine Schuld"?

Tags: word-usage, negation, modal-particle

I'm trying to understand a particular use of the word **doch**

If somebody says **es ist meine Schuld**,  meaning "it's my fault", may I use **doch** in response to convey, essentially, "no, on the contrary, it's not your fault"?

Comment: I've tried to be more clear in my question, let me know if that helps explain what I'm trying to grasp.

Comment: You might want to give an example of the Q and A that you were thinking about. And maybe what made you think of this usage. If you're unsure, don't edit your question but write it in a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me try to give you an idea on how to use *"doch"* in that particular context with a short story:

> 1. **Anna:** Peter, du hast doch nicht etwa den Tee verschüttet, oder? - *Peter, it wasn't you who spilled the tea, was it?*
> 2. **Peter:** Doch, es ist meine Schuld. - *Yes, is is my fault.*
> 3. **Anna:** Gabi, mach das doch bitte sauber! - *Gabi, would you please clean this up.*
> 4. **Peter:** Warum Gabi? Es war doch **meine** Schuld! - *Why Gabi? It was me who's fault it was.*
> 5. **Anna:** Gabi stellte doch den Tee dort hin. - *But it was Gabi who put the tea there.*
> 6. **Peter:** Also ist es **doch** nicht meine Schuld. - *But then it is not really my fault.*
> 7. **Anna:** Du hättest besser acht geben sollen. - *You should have watched out more.*
> 8. **Peter:** Ist es also **doch** meine Schuld. - *So it is my fault then.*
> 9. **Anna:** Ja, doch ich verzeihe dir. - *Yes, but I forgive you.*
> 10. **Gabi:** Soll ich nun putzen? - *Do I have to clean up now?*
> 11. **Anna:** Aber nein, es ist doch nicht Deine Schuld, Peter hat es getan. - *No you don't have to, it is not your fault at all. Peter did it.*

You can see that depending on context *doch* is used in different meanings that can not be translated 1:1. It gets further comlicated because the meanig of a sentence may change with emphasis (see 4., 6., 8.). Example 11. may come close to what you asked.

We can use *"doch"* as an [adverb](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/doch_dennoch), as a [particle](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/doch_gewiss_noch), or as [conjunction](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/doch_aber). You will find further examples in the referenced Duden entries, and also in [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/995/23).

Comment: If you keep going on even I do not know anymore, how "doch" is used correctly ;)

Comment: Great answer, I understand this context a little better now. Your answer will no doubt be a good reference for me to refer back to if in doubt – thanks.

Comment: It is indeed a nice example but when you take a close look the vast majority of the doch in there is the doch replying to a negative. The one of : nein - doch. There are a lot of meanings missing.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible. *Doch* can only be used as a response to negative statements. For example, if someone says

> Es ist nicht meine Schuld.

then you can answer

> Doch.

to express that you think it is their fault (although they deny). I believe there's no short translation for this *doch* to English.

If someone says

> Es ist meine Schuld.

then it doesn't make sense to simply answer with *Doch*, but you could very well say

> Das stimmt doch gar nicht.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to determine. I read somewhere else that you can only say doch in response to a negative statement, and I wrongly thought that 'it is my fault' is negative, but of course, 'it is *not* my fault' is the negative – and so 'doch' in response means 'on the contrary, it is your fault'.

Comment: The short English version of that "Doch!" is something like "Yes, it is [your fault]!"

Answer (score 2):

"Es ist meine Schuld" is a complete sentence, means *It's my fault*

*it's not your fault* would be:

> "Es ist nicht deine Schuld."

If you see somebody is punished for something you did, you may say (directing the sentence to the punisher):

> "Es ist doch meine Schuld"

Or you could use it to console somebody (*Don't worry, it's my fault*). But it needs the statement, somebody else is taken the blame or feels responsible for your fault.